# Rails mongodb error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have rails 4.2.2 And I am using mongodb . I am using internationalization and facebook authentication .But when I am trying to authentiate 
It gives me this error

> translation missing: en-US.mongoid.errors.messages.message_title:
>   translation missing:
>   en-US.mongoid.errors.messages.no_client_config.message translation
>   missing: en-US.mongoid.errors.messages.summary_title:   translation
>   missing: en-US.mongoid.errors.messages.no_client_config.summary
>   translation missing: en-US.mongoid.errors.messages.resolution_title:
>   translation missing:
>   en-US.mongoid.errors.messages.no_client_config.resolution

Comment: please post config/locales/en-US.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this on your locales file `config/locales/en-US.yml`

```
en-US:
  mongoid:
    errors:
      messages:
        no_client_config:
          message: "Test"
          summary: "Test Summary"
          resolution: "Test Resolution"
```